# Has anyone integrated Sage One with django framework?

Tags: django, sage-one

I wanted to integrate Sage One with my django application. But, from https://developers.sageone.com/ I got to know that it supports only C#, Java, PHP and Ruby. Did anyone integrated "Sage One" with django framework?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The Sage One API is a general REST API with OAuth2 authentication. With that, it is completely neutral to the language of the client.

The sample clients/apps that you mentioned are only there to provide a faster start into client development. By no means this should limit your choice of language or framework.

Comment: To add the one helpful resource I have found: https://github.com/maxnaude/sageone-api-client

That is for Sage One ZA, though.